# Window Comparator

Tags: comparator

I am reading this website and don't understand why this circuit doesn't blow up. If Vin = Vcc then seems to me top opamp A1 would drive low (Vcc > 2/3Vcc and inverting comparator) and the bottom one A2 would drive high (Vcc > 1/3Vcc and non-inverting comparator). So now you have two opamps driving against each other and whichever one overheats first looses.

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html

[image]

Comment: Comparator op-amps can have an open-collector output.

Comment: @Oldfart I would give you the correct answer but can't do it if it's a comment.

Comment: I am now fully reading the full text in detail to see if they mention it somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no issue if the output is an open collector type.

I found the text in the article you where referring to:

> As a result the output stage of the voltage comparator is generally
>   configured as a single open collector (or Drain) transistor switch
>   with open or closed states rather than actual output voltages as
>   shown:
>
> [image]